# OSX AppStore Avoid updating certain apps

Tags: macos, software-update

Is it possible to avoid updating certain Applications in OSX from AppStore. The idea behind is to avoid unnecessary updates.

For instance, I want to avoid updating iMovie as I don’t use that so often and it is usually 200 MB.

*Note: I know that I have to click "Update" in AppStore for the update to start and currently I still haven't updated this application. I want to know if there is a way for it to not show in the AppStore Updates itself or to ignore it till a next update is available.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the *More* button at the bottom of the listed item, then right click after it has expanded, you should get a 'Hide Update' button - but it doesn't work for all apps.

Tested today with

- Camera Raw 5.0.7 - Hide Update button
- OS X Update 10.9.5 - Hide Update button
- Xcode 6.0.1 - **no** Hide Update button