# How to hide app store updates in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I tried right clicking the updates to see if it would show me a "hide" or "ignore" option without any luck.

My OCD is not pleased. I don't want to see a number on my pretty App Store icon :p

Am I missing anything or did Apple just remove that option? If so, may Steve Job's ghost haunt them until they are all driven crazy.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145973/3641; right-click works for some things, but not e.g. Xcode.

Comment: Flash Sheridan's linked answer is over four years old, and is obsolete. There is now never a 'Hide Update' option.

Answer (score 1):

**To hide an update:**

1. Open the Mac App Store and click the Updates tab.
2. Right click on the update(s) that you wish to hide, and click Hide Update.

Example:

[image: hide]

**To unhide an update:**

1. Open the Mac App Store
2. Click the Store tab in the menu bar and select Show All Software Updates.

Example:

[image: unhide]

Why there could have been no option:

> Right-Click "Hide update" worked in Sierra through 10.12.4. Some time in the last couple of updates it stopped being an option. However: Updates you previously "hid" (in an earlier version of Sierra) are still flagged as "hidden" and still stay out of sight, you just cant add any new items to hide.

Comment: That is not what the latest mac app store looks like. Your answer is obsolete,